# NGINX: search file in subdirectories

Tags: nginx, system-administration

Part of nginx config:

```
    location = / {
        root   www/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html;

    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
        root www/resources/img;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
        #autoindex         on;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location ~* \.(css)$ {
        root www/resources/css;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location ~* \.(js)$ {
        root www/resources/js;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
```

In directory `www/resources/img` I have 1 image file `1.jpg` and 1 subfolder which contain another file `2.jpg`. So, if I do request like `localhost/1.jpg` I get my image, but if I do request `localhost/2.jpg` it returns 404 not found. How to setup nginx to search file in subfolders?

Comment: localhost/1.jpg --> www/resources/img/1.jpg, but localhost/2.jpg --> www/resources/img/subfolder/2.jpg ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing below block of code, for if the file not found in root, find it in /subfolder/$uri,

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
    root www/resources/img;
    try_files $uri /subfolder/$uri $uri/;
    #autoindex         on;
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Switch your error_log on, to see which file is being accessed, and you might correct from their as well.